# Transform/Parsing data in python pandas to appropriate data types

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, amazon-s3, presto

I've data coming from source files in python code where I've to parse data using pandas. Parsed data will be written to s3 location as parquet which is an underlying path for an external presto table. Presto column datatypes should match the pandas parsed types

Source Data :
**employee_name** : *string*,
**employee_salary** : *string*,
**hire_date** : *string* (which timestamp included)

We want data in Presto table to be with below datatypes
**employee_name** : *string*,
**employee_salary** : *Decimal/Double*,
**hire_date** : *Date*

We use below to parse the data using pandas:

```
df['employee_name']     = df['employee_name'].astype(str)
df['hire_date']         = pd.to_datetime(df['hire_date'].str[:19]).dt.date
df['employee_salary']   = pd.to_numeric(df['employee_salary'])
```

This df then gets written to s3 as parquet file which is underlying file for Presto table. Once we query presto table we will get data in required format on which we could apply data functions etc.

Comment: Are you experiencing a problem? What is your question?

Comment: Which Presto version are you using?

Comment: Presto Version : 0.236